# How to select anchor tag with specified class and rel?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, anchor, rel

I have an anchor tag like this, and I need to select it!

```
<a href="#" class="foo bar" rel="123">...</a>
```

Is it possible with jQuery to write a selector that selects an anchor that has class like `foo bar` and rel like `123`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$('a.foo.bar[rel="123"]')
```